# Why is parameter not a constant expression?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14

Could you please explain why this code doesn't compile?

```
// source.cpp
constexpr const char* func(const char* s) { return s;}

constexpr bool find(const char *param) {
   constexpr const char* result = func(param);
   return (param == 0);
}

int main()
{
   constexpr bool result = find("abcde");
}
```

The compile command:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 source.cpp
```

I've tried gcc5.4 and gcc6.4. The error:

```
source.cpp: In function ‘constexpr bool find(const char*)’:
source.cpp:5:46: error: ‘param’ is not a constant expression
 constexpr const char* result = func(param);
                                          ^
```

Comment: A string is not an integral value so it cannot be resolved during compilation. This contradicts the `constexpr` definition of find. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A function parameter is never a constant expression. Remember that `constexpr` functions are just like regular functions. They can be called at run-time too. So we cannot assume the address passed in `param` is to something that is a constant expression, and so cannot use it to initialize a `constexpr` variable or return value.

You *can* pass string literals to `constexpr` functions and produce `constexpr` results, [for instance](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/762c5ea13f9ce95d):

```
constexpr bool find(const char *param) {
   return (param[0] == 0);
}

int main()
{
   constexpr bool result = find("abcde"); // OK!
}
```

The function is callable in a constant expression, when given a constant expression. But it cannot assume it is only ever called in a constant expression (I know, one can go cross-eyed thinking about it).

Comment: Your example uses parameter to produce a constant expression, right? My example do the same. What is the difference?

Comment: @embedc - The difference is that your example assumes the argument is unconditionally `constexpr`, mine does not.