# not a constant expression error when assigning constexpr result to variable

Tags: c++, constexpr

This simple program compiles fine:

```
#include <string_view>

constexpr int f(std::string_view s) { return 1; }

constexpr int g(std::string_view s) {
  return f(s);
}

int main()
{
  constexpr int i = f("hello");

  return 0;
}
```

With a small modification, however, it stops to compile:

```
#include <string_view>

constexpr int f(std::string_view s) { return 1; }

constexpr int g(std::string_view s) {
    constexpr int res = f(s);
    return res;
}

int main()
{
  constexpr int i = f("hello");

  return 0;
}
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/qWqE7nT9f) where the program can be tested.

The compiler complains that since the argument of the function is not known, the variable res cannot be `constexpr`.
I presume this is because the `constexpr` functions can, but not must, be used in a `constexpr` context, hence `res` could not be constant.

**Is it possibile, within c++17, to store the result of `f(s)` in a constexpr variable, that I can further use in constexpr expressions?**

I could think to make the `string_view s` a template parameter but, unfortunately, this is not allowed, at least with c++17...

A bit of background: the question arises because, in a real code, the argument (and hence the result) of g can be invalid and, when used in a constexpr expression (such as index in `std::get`) will make the program to not compile. Rather than having a long error, I'd rather use a `static_assert` to provide a meaningful compilation error message. Something like:

```
constexpr int g(std::string_view s) {
    constexpr int res = f(s);
    static_assert(res < 4, "invalid string s");
    return res;
}
```

But clearly this is not possible if `res` cannot be `constexpr`.

Comment: Like many before you, you discovered that function arguments are never considered to be constexpr inside of the function. :P Report your errors by e.g. throwing an exception, which conveniently causes a build error when done in `constexpr` context at compile-time.

Comment: [*A function parameter is never a constant expression.* /Why is parameter not a constant expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54421519/why-is-parameter-not-a-constant-expression)

Comment: I would have wrote an answer specifically for this problem. Basically, you need `fixed_string`

Comment: Maybe you want `consteval` ?